# Can we dynamically update the reactnative/android application without going to app store?

Tags: android, react-native

Can we dynamically/problematically update the reactnative/android  application without going to app store etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can. Hot code push is the technique to dynamically update the app without forcing users to update the app from play store.
Refer this:-
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as your react native code is a bundled JavaScript file, this file can be served from anywhere. Although you can set this up yourself, the most popular service is CodePush created by Microsoft

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push